# ref not working in react native as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ref

I am using ref to access the TextInput in order to focus it dynamically. when the Remote debug option is enabled in react native the current node value is as expected (all the properties are available) but as soon as the remote debugger is disabled on android studio the current node is not getting displayed and the value is undefined.

```
"react": "16.8.6",
"react-native": "0.60.4",
```

```
import React, { createRef} from 'react';
import {TextInput} from 'react-native';

class demo extends React.Component {
 constructor(props){
   this.inputRef = createRef();
 } 

 display= ()=> {
   console.log(this.inputRef.current)
 }

  return(
    <TextInput
      ref={this.inputRef}
      style={styles.modelOpenViewMain}
    />
    <Button onPress={this.display}>DISPLAY</Button>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Copy/pasted your code into an [Expo snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@drew.w.reese/tactless-cookie) and it seems to function as I'd expect. It's not clear what any issue is here.

Comment: for some reason, it's not working for me in react native: "0.60.4"